# How to disable window caption bar in GNU Screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I usually split my GNU Screen into four regions, and I don't really need the status bars for each of those windows.

Is there an option to disable GNU Screen window status bars?

I could only find caption always|split only in the manual.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
hardstatus ignore
```

Try putting it in your `~/.screenrc`.

This will override any setting that's in `/etc/screenrc`.

If that doesn't work, try

```
hardstatus off
```

Comment: mmm... i think hardstatus is a line on the very bottom.  and caption bar - is a separate bar for every separate window (so I have 4 of them).

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what you mean now.  Sorry, no easy way to do that as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

You can't disable it to get back some more screen real estate, but you can change its colour so that it "disappears"...

Add the following to your `.screenrc`:

```
caption string "%{kk}XXXXXXX"
```

So, how does this work? Well assuming your screen terminal background is black, you are making the caption strings background and foreground black as well. "k" stands for black, the first is for the foreground and the second one is for the background. The "XXXXXX"s are simply a string to make it work.

I guess if you have chosen a different background colour for your main terminal, you simply change kk to whatever colour you have chosen. Yes, you get a small gap, but not as in your face as the big bars across the screen.

Comment: Brilliant! 5 more to go...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the text but keep the window divider, just do:

`caption string " "`

in your .screenrc